# Headers aren't bold on profile but the editor lies

Tags: bug, profile-page, markdown, markdown-preview

See [my profile](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/102999/stormblessed?tab=profile) ([archive from when this was written](https://web.archive.org/web/20190722181403if_/https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/102999/stormblessed?tab=profile)). The text at the top of my bio is a header, and it is not bold other than a word I put in bold:

[image: The header is not bold]

However, the editor lies! It looks bold in the preview:

[image: It is shown as all being bold in the preview]

The markdown for the header:

> `# Please read *Skulduggery Pleasant*, it is an amazing series and we only have **one** question about it here, unfortunately.`